# ASP.NET MVC routing: URL is falling into the wrong route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, url-routing

I'm working into a really common mvc Project and I have three diferents routes:

**Route for display products by id**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "get-by-id",
            "{controller}/{id}",
            new { action = "GetById" },
            new { id = @"\d+" }
            );
```

**Route for display products by category**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "get-by-category",
            "{controller}/{category}",
            new { action = "GetByCategory" },
            new { category = @"\w+" }
            );
```

**Default route**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Conslusion:** I want the */products/create* request falls into the *default* route (*because I want "create" to be rendered as an action*) and not into the *get-by-category* route (*because it take "create" as a string*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Route Debuger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) it will help you debug your routes to figure out which routes are being called when. One of the tools I always nuget when working on asp.net mvc.

BTW - looking at your routes there is no route there that maps to Product/Create. In which case it is just going to take you to the default route. You need to have a route specified which is going to map to the Products controller and if you want to have an action of Create it will need to have "Products/Create" with its action pointing to Get-by-id action

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "get-by-id",
        "{controller}/Create/{id}",
        new { action = "GetById" },
        new { id = @"\d+" }
        );
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I make a few errors on the post, now feel free to help.

Comment: You're actual route should look like - Product/GetById/Create - currently it is looking for a Product/Create where it assumes that "Create" is the name of the action

Comment: I use a regular expression at get-by-category route constraint to pass to the next route when the Word after product is create...